# Signalr connectionid in client side disconnect event

Tags: javascript, signalr

How to get signalr connection id in client side disconnect event? I am using below method but $.connection.hub.id is always undefined.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            var ConnectionID = $.connection.hub.id;
            alert(ConnectionID);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one way you could do it is to create your own property on the `hub` object that stores the `id` when a connection to the server hub is established.

```
$.connection.hub.start(function() {
    $.connection.hub.__myConnection = $.connection.hub.id;

});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    alert($.connection.hub.__myConnection );
});
```